# Yes/No Prompt in C?

Tags: c

I'm using a Yes/No user prompt to determine whether the user wants to go through the program or exit the program...when you type y or Y it will go through the program again. However, any other character, not just n or N, will discontinue the program. I was wondering how I could fix this?

```
int main() {
    unsigned num;
    char response;

    do {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer greater than 1 and less than 2000: ");
        scanf("%d", & num);
        if(num > 1 && num < 2000) {
            printf("All the prime factors of %d are given below: \n", num);
            printPrimeFactors(num);
            printf("\n\nThe distinct prime factors of %d are given below: \n", num);
            printDistinctPrimeFactors(num);
        } else {
            printf("Sorry that number does not fall within the given range.\n");
        }
        printf("\n\nDo you want to try another number? Say Y(es) or N(o): ");
        getchar();
        response = getchar();
    }
    while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y'); // if response is Y or y then program runs again
        printf("Thank you for using my program. Good Bye!\n\n"); //if not Y or y, program terminates
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If Y makes them continue and N makes them exit, what do you want the other letters to do?

Comment: i want the other letters to not be able to discontinue the program like N does...like "You typed something other than Yes or No, please try again"

Comment: Well, isn't this behavior exactly you want? Or what does need to be fixed?

Comment: Exactly. Maybe you need to think about what you want your program to do if you don't get a "y"/"Y", or "n"/"N". Do you want to exit on an error? Do you want the user to be given another opportunity to choose y/n?

Comment: "This question is unlikely to help any future visitor" - say what now??!!??   I would imagine that *every* Command line program with user interaction needs something like this. I know that I do, and when I Googled, this was the first hit. How do I vote to reopen this? There needs to be answer awarded.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are expecting the below logic to get only `y`, `Y`, `n` or `N` as input from use to take a decision.

```
do
{
    ...

    r = getchar();
    if (r == '\n') r = getchar();
    while(r != 'n' && r != 'N' && r != 'y` && r != `Y`)
    {
        printf("\invalid input, enter the choice(y/Y/n/N) again : ");
        r = getchar();
        if (r == '\n') r = getchar();
    }
}while(r == 'Y' || r == 'y');
```

Comment: this is good. only problem is when i enter a character other than Y/y N/n it will infinitely say that printf statement

Comment: You are expecting the correct input form the user right then loop needs to be done for getting that

Comment: yeah so if they enter the incorrect input, as you wrote code for above...how can i make it so it says invalid input just once instead it runs infinitely

Comment: inside the `while` loop after printing `invalid input` one more `getchar` i am doing to get the input second time, that loop will not break untill unless user enters correct value. Each iteration is doing `getchar` right.

Comment: oops never mind it works, except it does the print statement twice

Comment: two times printing `invalid input` means second `getchar` is reading some line feed character from `stdin` which was given along with first time. do fflush after `getchar`.

Comment: updated my answer... try now.. with fflush...

Comment: i have to use getchar...this is an assignment...i can use fflush...so how do i fix it so its just one line of the print statement

Comment: are you able to give the input second time now?

Comment: yes it works fine...but it shows the print statement twice and on the second print statement output i can enter input and everything works...how can i get rid of that first print statement

Comment: if you getting two times printf after adding fflush means try with `rewind(stdin)` instead of `fflush(stdin)`. Because in ANSI C compiler `fflush(stdin)` will not work.

Comment: i cant add fflush...this is a homework assignment. we have not yet used fflush, and i am not yet allowed to use it.

Comment: there is a valid reason to use the `fflush`. Its not like you have to use which ever taught by your professor. Or use `getchar` two times in allplace.

Comment: i cant use it. i just emailed my professor and they said not to.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. It is unbelievable people upvoted this.

Comment: @cnicutar Updated my answer to do `getchar` second time if line feed character present in `stdin` buffer. In ANSI C compiler fflush(stdin) is an undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> any other character, not just n or N, will discontinue the program. I
>   was wondering how I could fix this

In that case you probably want to test:

```
while(tolower(response) != 'n'));
```

I can only presume the empty `getchar()` is there to throw away the newline. There are better ways to do this but in this case you could simply add a space to the scanf:

```
scanf("%d ", &num);
         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is since you are using two `getchar()` in your program. .

We dont know the error. still you can try removing the `getchar()` immediately after the `printf` in your program.

Comment: I noticed this too, I don't know if this is the problem however.

Comment: @NlightNFotis The first is there to remove the newline left in the input buffer from the `scanf`. If the input is as expected, it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally... you may want to replace

```
getchar();
response = getchar();
```

with:

```
char c;
do{
    printf("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
    scanf(" %c",&c); c = toUpper(c);
}while(c != 'N');
```

Note that (though not necessary), the space ahead of %c is to eliminate white spaces

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the line that reads `getchar();` with `fflush(stdin);`

Working well for me, this is the complete code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    unsigned num;
    char response;

    do {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer greater than 1 and less than 2000: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num > 1 && num  < 2000){
            printf("All the prime factors of %d are given below: \n", num);
            printPrimeFactors(num);
            printf("\n\nThe distinct prime factors of %d are given below: \n", num);
            printDistinctPrimeFactors(num);
        }
        else{
            printf("Sorry that number does not fall within the given range.\n");
        }

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\nDo you want to try another number? Say Y(es) or N(o): ");
        response = getchar();
    } while(response == 'Y' || response == 'y');

    printf("Thank you for using my program. Good Bye!\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour per the standard. It may work with some implementations, but it's certainly not portable.